# VBA: Within Excel how do I save a word document as a PDF?

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, ms-word

I have some code that copies and pastes data from an Excel file into a word document, how can I get that word document to save as a PDF?

My code is as follows:

```
Sub RetailerGraphs()

Dim Location As String
Dim Detail As String

Worksheets("-Summary").Activate
Range("AE9").Select
While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Location = ActiveCell.Value
    Worksheets("Detail Summary").Activate
    Range("B7").Value = Location

    Dim objWord, objDoc As Object
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

    Range("AH40").Select
    While ActiveCell <> ""
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Detail = ActiveCell.Value
        Range("B11").Value = Detail 
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        Range("A1:Z111").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        objWord.Visible = True
        objWord.Selection.Paste
        objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
        Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
        objSelection.InsertBreak (wdPageBreak)
        If ActiveCell.Value = "END" Then
             objWord.SaveAs2 "C:\Docs\MyDoc.pdf"
        End If
    Wend
    Worksheets("-Summary").Activate
Wend

End Sub
```

Within the lines:

```
If ActiveCell.Value = "END" Then

End If
```

I have tried the following code to try to get it to save as a PDF:

```
 objWord.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="C:\wordtest.pdf", _
  ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF

 objWord.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\YourFile.pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF

 objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\YourFile.pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
```

But I get the error on the line where I try to export it as a PDF, e.g. `objWord.SaveAs2 "C:\Docs\MyDoc.pdf"` :

```
Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Can someone please help?

Note: I have ensured that "Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library" is ticked in the references, and I change the location to the necessary directory rather than using the above.

Comment: Not VBA and probably not the answer you want to hear, but I would take a look at ITextSharp and Codaxy-WKHTMLToPDF.  Turns out (in my experience), it is easier to render html and turn that into PDF than any other route.  If you can write VBA to execute a command line which runs a CSharp app using one of the for mentioned libraries, you'll probably have better luck.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but I'd rather stick with VBA and Word

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Sorry I should have added that, please see the edit

Comment: Try using the following .SaveAs2 FileName:="...", _ FileFormat:=..., objWord.SaveAs

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand the format of what you've just suggested, are you saying to put `objWord.SaveAs2 FileName:= "C:\Docs\MyDoc.pdf",  FileFormat:=PDF, objWord.SaveAs`?

Comment: Yeah.  I'm saying try specifying the form right there in the SaveAs

Comment: I've just tried it, had the same error appear

Comment: Open a document in Word, start the macro recorder, save the document as PDF, stop the macro recorder, examine the generated macro code.  Then copy it into your Excel VBA code and adapt as needed.

Comment: @Joe Joe's idea is a really good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ExportAsFixedFormat` is a method of Word.Document (objDoc), not Word.Application (objWord). So

```
objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="C:\Docs\File.pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
```

should work.

Does this give an error too? Which?

Answer (score 0):

Call `wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(strFile, 17)`.

[WdExportFormat enumeration (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdexportformat)