# Exporting as PDF in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I would like to create an automated certificate issuing process that allows me to "save as" an existing documents with a new title, and creates a PDF of it.

The problem I'm facing this is in the PDF export routine, I've commented below.

```
Sub GerarCertificado()

Dim Word As Word.Application
Dim DOC As Word.Document
Dim aux As Long

For aux = Range("F8").Value To Range("F11").Value

Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Word.Visible = True

Set DOC = Word.Documents.Open("C:\Users\vitor\Downloads\Certificados\Declaracao.doc")

With DOC

.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "#NOME"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection.Range = Sheets("Gerar Certificado").Cells(aux, 1)

.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "#PALESTRA"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection.Range = Sheets("Gerar Certificado").Cells(aux, 2)

.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "#HORAS"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection.Range = Sheets("Gerar Certificado").Cells(aux, 3)

.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "#DIA"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection.Range = Sheets("Gerar Certificado").Cells(aux, 4)

.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "#DATA"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection.Range = Sheets("Gerar Certificado").Cells(aux, 5)

.SaveAs ("C:\Users\vitor\Downloads\Certificados\Certificados\" & Sheets("Gerar Certificado").Cells(aux, 1) & ".doc")

'Here starts the error
.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=_
    "C:\Users\vitor\Downloads\Certificados\Certificados\" & Sheets("Gerar Certificado").Cells(aux, 1) & ".pdf",_
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF,_
    OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=_
    wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent,_
    IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:=_
    wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:=_
    True, UseISO19005_1:=False

.Close

Word.Quit
Set DOC = Nothing
Set Word = Nothing

End With

Next aux

MsgBox "Certificados gerados com sucesso!", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Can anyone help with it or improve it for a better solution? I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: You dont even say what the error is...

Comment: Compilation error: Syntax error.

Comment: Record the macro again and compare it to what you have - pay attention to anything you changed.

Comment: [Previous thread, excel vba save word doc as pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187516/vba-within-excel-how-do-i-save-a-word-document-as-a-pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to put a space before each of the underscores at the end of the line. like this:

now

```
.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=_
```

change like this

```
.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I posted the correction in another post.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, thank you. Bellow is the correction.

```
.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
"C:\Users\vitor\Downloads\Certificados\Certificados\" & Sheets("Gerar Certificado").Cells(aux, 1) & ".pdf", _
ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:= _
wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:= _
True, UseISO19005_1:=False
```

Comment: Nice easy fix. If Sergiu answered your question, please check his answer as the answer. Your answer is not required.